# Use a function to pass a file into a class method, and use the file in the method to access private object attributes. Trying to "load" a saved object

Tags: c++, file, oop, methods, fstream

I'm trying to make a save/load function in my program. I have the saving part down, it works well. I'm trying to do a reverse of the save and load the object instead. I passed the file into the object method, but i'm doing something wrong. I can't figure out how to assign the private attributes from the data in the file.

```
case '2':// load character
      game = load();
      if(game == 4 || game == 5 || game == 6){
        newgame(game-3);
      }
      else{
        hero herosave;
        loadgame(game, herosave);
      }
      break;
```

```
void loadgame(int save, hero newhero){
  if(save == 1){
    ifstream file1("hero1.txt");
    newhero.loadStats(file1);
    file1.close();
    }
    if(save == 2){
    ifstream file2("hero2.txt");
    newhero.loadStats(file2);
    file2.close();
    }
    if(save == 3){
    ifstream file3("hero2.txt");
    newhero.loadStats(file3);
    file3.close();
    }
}
```

```
class hero{
private:
string name;
string race;
string heroclass;
int strength, wisdom, charisma;
int dexterity, intelligence, constitution;
int hitpoints, AC;



public:
hero();
void setName(string);
void setRace(int);
void setClass(int);
void setStats();
string getRace();
string getClass();
string getName();
int getStr();
int getWis();
int getCha();
int getDex();
int getInt();
int getCon();
int setAC();
void loadStats(ifstream &);
};
```

```
void hero::loadStats(ifstream &file){
  file >> name;
//THIS IS WHERE IM HAVING ISSUES
}
```

```
Bilbo Baggins
Halfling
Rogue
16
13
6
9
7
16
```

Comment: What is the issue? You can simply assign them, they are visible in `loadStats()`.

Comment: I'm not sure how to assign them in loadStats(ifstream &file) 
when I use file >> name; I get 
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::ifstream' (aka 'basic_ifstream<char>') and 'std::string' (aka 'basic_string<char>'))
file >> name;

Comment: There should be more to the error message, specifically it should tell you what the invalid operands are and what it expected. What you have shown (once I add the missing headers) works (https://godbolt.org/z/4cG3hee4x), so the mistake is elsewhere. Perhaps you have two things named `name` or you left out one of the headers.

Comment: Constructing a [mre] (MRE) should help you find the problem. If it doesn't, update the question to include the MRE.

Comment: There's a very likely explanation for that compilation error, but unfortunately the shown code fails to meet all requirements for a [mre], and until that happens the only thing that anyone can reply with is a random guess. A random guess does not qualify as an answer.

Comment: I got it guys! My functions.h had #include <fstream> but my character.h did not.
i added #include <fstream> to character.h and the method is working now

Answer (score 0):

I failed to `#include <fstream>` in my header file containing the class hero. `#include <fstream>` was on my header file containing functions and had `#include <fstream>` but it was not included on my class header file.